# Encapsulation of process handling creates problems

Tags: c++, process, fork

My assignment requires me to encapsulate the principle of process handling.

Here's what my `Process` class contains:

```
class Process
{
public:
  Process();
  ~Process();

  pid_t getPid() const;

private:
  pid_t         pid_;
};
```

Constructor:

```
Process::Process()
{
  this->pid_ = fork();
}
```

Destructor:

```
Process::~Process()
{
  if (this->pid_ > 0)
    kill(this->pid_, SIGKILL);
}
```

Here's the problem: after encapsulating and creating an object like such:

```
void    example()
{
  Process       pro;

  if (pro.pid_ == 0)
    {
      // Child Process                                                                                                      
    }
  else if (pro.pid_ < 0)
    {
      // Error                                                                                                         
    }
  else
    {
      // Parent Process                                                                                                     
    }
}
```

My program almost never enters the child code, but when I `fork()` normally (with no encapsulation) it works like a charm.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). In your case the parent most of the time seems to kill the child before it does what you expected from it. Without synchronization between the two processes, any execution order is possible. If you want the child always to perform work, you have to implement some form of synchronization. A common hack (i.e. not really synchronization) is `[sleep][2]()`ing in the parent. Very common is `[wait][2]()`ing in the parent for completion of the child.

Comment: Interesting ! But is there another way around this issue than a sleep or a wait that will impair my algorithm? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: There are many more synchronization methods, One way of synchronization is using communication, e.g. pipes, files, Another way is using constructs that were made especially for synchronization, e.g. semaphores or wait. I do not know enough of your problem to choose the best,

Comment: I'll certainly use Named Pipes since the assignment mentions it. Thank you very much for your help.